# Using for loop with qsub for batch job submission

Tags: for-loop, qsub

Could I please be advised how I could use a for loop to qsub files for batch job submission?

At the moment, this only works if I submit a single file for job submission using the command:

```
qsub -v /path/to/file.txt script.sh
```

However if I run a for loop through files using the following commands:

```
files=`pwd`/*pattern* (#This gives a list of files containing a certain common title)

for i in $files;
do
qsub -v $i script.sh
done
```

This always gets rejected with the error that the file.txt was not provided.

I have double checked if $i from the for loop is providing the right file.txt by doing:

```
for i in $files;
do
echo $i
done
```

and this works out fine. As such I am unsure why the for loop with qsub is not working. Could I please get advice on how I could alter the code to get it to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using -v requires you to give the variable a name: `qsub -v filepath=$i script.sh` where you can then access the filepath inside `script.sh` with `$filepath`.